# Rails 4 render simple-form NEW in INDEX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, simple-form

While trying to render out simple_form new in index.I have followed http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/layouts_and_rendering.html ,,in that 2.2.2 Rendering an Action’s View and i am getting error NoMethodError in Posts#index ,undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

```html
class PostsController < ApplicationController
 before_action :find_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
 before_action :authenticate_user!,except:[:index,:show]

 def index
  @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")
  render 'new'
 end
 
 def new
  @post = current_user.posts.build
 end




index.html.haml

- if user_signed_in?
 = link_to "New Post", new_post_path

- @posts.each do |post|
 %h2.post= link_to post.post, post
 %h4.post= link_to post.location, post
 %h4.post= link_to post.tag_list, post
 %p.date
  Published at
  = time_ago_in_words(post.created_at)
  by
  = post.user.email



_form.html.haml

= simple_form_for @post do |f|
 = f.input :post
 = f.input :location
 = f.input :tag_list
 = f.input :active
 = f.submit


new.html.haml

%h1 Post 

= render 'form'
```

Comment: Can you post the logs ?

Comment: @ahmadhamza Sorry what logs ?? new to rails ..

Comment: Logs means your terminal output.

Comment: => Post(id: integer, post: text, location: string, tag_list: string, active: boo
lean, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, user_id: integer)

Comment: NilClass:Class means that you are getting an empty array. Can you paste the exact logs from the terminal. It does mention the line number and the file name.

Comment: See, when you are loading the `index page`, you have written in the controller to `render new` which is not necessary because you have already mention in the `index` file.

Comment: It is pointing  to c:/Sites/tag/app/views/posts/_form.html.haml                      = simple_form_for @post do |f|

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76784/discussion-between-ahmad-hamza-and-akhil-ranjith).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove `render new` from the controller, as you have already mentioned it in the view file `index.html.haml` file. 
Also your controller will look like this as you are getting `NilClass` error.:

```
def index
    @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")
    @post = Post.new
end
```

Comment: Thank you for soling it . Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Let's clear things up.

Your controller have several `actions` which basically correspond to "what do I want to do...in one single page render/AJAX request". I believe what isn't clear for you, is that displaying an index AND displaying a form on the same page, correspond to a unique controller action!

Now what you want to do, as ahmad hamza suggested, it to instanciate two variables in your `index` action

- `@posts` in which you will put the list of all posts (the index)
- `@new_post` which correspond to a new post that the user can add directly from the index

  ```
  def index
      @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")
      @new_post = current_user.posts.build
  end
  ```

Now, maybe you also have other actions in which you want to display a form to create new posts, not just in the index.

That is why we usually write `partials` to do this stuff. However, a good idea is to make these partials reusable anywhere, without restricting the variable name.

in other words, you want

*/views/posts/_form.html.haml*

```
= simple_form_for post do |f| # Notice : not @post but post 
    = ...
```

Now from your index file, you want to show some content AND a form for `@new_post`

*/views/posts/index.html.haml*

```
- if user_signed_in?
= link_to "New Post", new_post_path

- @posts.each do |post|
    %h2.post= link_to post.post, post
    %h4.post= link_to post.location, post
    %h4.post= link_to post.tag_list, post
    %p.date
        Published at
        = time_ago_in_words(post.created_at)
        by
        = post.user.email
- render 'form', post = @new_post
```

Comment: Thank you for clearing thing up , your explanation was helpful , Cheers